# Erros Post Uploaded image with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, http-post, is-uploaded-file

I have question about upload-ing images with angularJS.

I'm using this code for upload image http://jsfiddle.net/sc1qnw4n/, that's code already made by someone.

```
$scope.uploadImage = function() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var imgBlob = dataURItoBlob($scope.uploadme);
  fd.append('file', imgBlob);
  $http.post(
      'imageURL',
      fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      }
    )
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log('success', response);
    })
    .error(function(response) {
      console.log('error', response);
    });
}
```

But when I press upload image i got this:

> error Cannot POST /imageURL

Has anyone had the same problem? Thank you :)

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not available.

Comment: I guess your service /imageURL doesn't exists. Are you using node.js or php for services?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the URL you are posting to.  Unless you give us more info we can't help.